# Insert many values in one column

Tags: sql, oracle, toad

I have created below table using TOAD.

```
CREATE TABLE TEM
( 
   No number
);
```

But i got below error when try to insert many values in "No" column.

My insert statement:

```
INSERT INTO TEM1k
(No)
VALUES
(8882323,454343);
```

Error Msg:

> ORA-00913: too many values

Appreciate your support to fix this issue.

Thanks,

Comment: Even with a DBMS that does support multi-row inserts, your syntax is wrong. You are inserting *one* row with *two* columns.

Comment: While a multi-row insert is possible in Oracle, IMO it doesn't really save you anything. To accomplish what you're attempting to do would be something like `INSERT ALL INTO TEM1K (NO) VALUES (8882323) INTO TEM1K (NO) VALUES (454343) SELECT * FROM DUAL', which is no great savings over two separate INSERT statements. This is really intended for use as a multi-TABLE insert, which honestly I've never found I needed, but YMMV. Best of luck.